# Webpage doesn't load the new version, only after clearing cache

Tags: css, html

My webpage doesn't load the renewed version by itself, only after cleaning cache and it is hapening with all the computers that have seen the older version, the ones that didn't everything is fine, has anyone faced anything like this? Anyone has an idea where the problem might be? The code or the browser? It is hapening with chrome and firefox, everything is fine with safari. Any kind of thoughts would be really helpfull.

website: http://bodygym.lt

```css
@media (min-width: 780px) {
#kainosmobile {display: none !important;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {margin-right: 110px !important; float: left !important; margin-top: 15px !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h3 {display: block !important; margin-bottom: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {display: block !important; right: unset !important; left: 80px !important}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
#kainos {display: none !important;}
#kainosmobile {display: initial !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {margin-right: 19% !important; float: left !important;margin-top: 15px !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h3 {display: block !important; margin-bottom: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {left: 80px !important; right: unset !important;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
div.wpb_wrapper.vc_custom_1469634122179 {padding: 15px !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {left: 30% !important; right: unset !important;}
}

.wtrShtTimeTableEntryName {padding: 0 !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableItem tbody td {text-align: left !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableFitnessEntry a {color: #222 !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableItem .wtrShtTimeTableFrom {text-align: left !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableEntryTimePeriod {width: 69% !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableFitnessEntry {background: transparent !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableEntryTimePeriod {color: #666 !important; font-weight: 400 !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableEntryName {padding: 0 !important;}
.wtrShtTimeTableFitnessEntry {color: #666 !important; font-weight: 400 !important; border-left: 1px solid #eb4c4c !important; border-radius: 0 !important; padding-left: 7px !important;}


.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {margin-right: 110px !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3 {line-height: 28px !important; font-weight: 400 !important; letter-spacing: 0px !important;}
.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {font-weight: 400 !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {font-weight: 400 !important; letter-spacing: 2px;}
#abonementas {display: none !important;}
#akcija {color: #ff3a49 !important;}
#galioja {color: #888 !important; font-size: 11px !important;}
#kainos .woocommerce ul.products li.product {margin-bottom: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;}
#kainos div.wtrPageContent.vcRow.wtrNoMargin.clearfix {background: #f9f9f9 !important; margin: 6% 6% 6% 6% !important; padding: 5px !important; border-radius: 10px !important;}
#kainos .vc_custom_1477331591093 {padding: 0 !important;}
#kainos .vc_custom_1477331604701 {padding: 0 !important;}
#kainos div.woocommerce {border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed !important;}

#kainosmobile .woocommerce ul.products li.product {margin-bottom: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;}
#kainosmobile div.wtrPageContent.vcRow.wtrNoMargin.clearfix {background: #f9f9f9 !important; margin: 6% 6% 6% 6% !important; padding: 5px !important; border-radius: 10px !important;}
#kainosmobile .vc_custom_1477331591093 {padding: 0 !important;}
#kainosmobile .vc_custom_1477331604701 {padding: 0 !important;}
#kainosmobile div.woocommerce {border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed !important;}
#kainosmobile div.woocommerce:nth-child(odd) {border-bottom: 0px solid #ededed !important;}
#kainosmobile div.woocommerce:nth-child(8) {border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed !important;}

.wrtAltFontCharacter {font-family: 'raleway' !important;}
```

This code does not appear on the screen, although it is loaded in http://www.bodygym.lt/wp-content/themes/symetrio-theme/style-custom.css?ver=4.6.1

Comment: Maybe add the code of the page?

Comment: You mean that the component for your page is being cached? Like `CSS`, `JavaScript`, `Font`, `Image`, and others, not the `HTML Page` itself right?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that helps is clearing the browser cache. But old clients will not understand that they need to do that.

PHP header cache controls and expires not helping, .css?=vx.x.x also not helping

Comment: Probably the browser, if your code works fine on other computers who didn't used the older version.

Comment: but this design change is critical and users who have cached the old css must now see the new one in order to understand the website itself.. is there a way to force clear the cache and download a new one? website: http://bodygym.lt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User browsers will cache website resources including images, CSS files and JavaScript files. To force an update I extended Magento by building a custom module which allows me specify a version number for the merged CSS and JS files. Every time I make a change to CSS I increment the version number which changes the filename and forces users browsers to download the new file.

etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <dev>
            <groups>
                <js>
                    <fields>
                        <js_files_version translate="label,comment">
                            <label>JavaScript Files Version</label>
                            <comment>Increment this to force browsers to download the latest version, as this will change the filename of the files.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </js_files_version>
                    </fields>
                </js>
                <css>
                    <fields>
                        <css_files_version translate="label,comment">
                            <label>CSS Files Version</label>
                            <comment>Increment this to force browsers to download the latest version, as this will change the filename of the files.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </css_files_version>
                    </fields>
                </css>
            </groups>
        </dev>
    </sections>
</config>
```

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JustKampers_Core>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </JustKampers_Core>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                 <design_package>JustKampers_Core_Model_Design_Package</design_package>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <justkampers_core>
                <class>JustKampers_Core_Block</class>
            </justkampers_core>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>JustKampers_Core_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Model/Design/Package.php

```
<?php

class JustKampers_Core_Model_Design_Package extends Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
{
    const XML_CONFIG_JS_FILES_VERSION = 'dev/js/js_files_version';
    const XML_CONFIG_CSS_FILES_VERSION = 'dev/css/css_files_version';

    /**
     * Merge specified css files and return URL to the merged file on success
     *
     * @param $files
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMergedCssUrl($files)
    {
        // secure or unsecure
        $isSecure = Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure();
        $mergerDir = $isSecure ? 'css_secure' : 'css';
        $targetDir = $this->_initMergerDir($mergerDir);
        if (!$targetDir) {
            return '';
        }

        // base hostname & port
        $baseMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media', $isSecure);
        $hostname = parse_url($baseMediaUrl, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $port = parse_url($baseMediaUrl, PHP_URL_PORT);
        if (false === $port) {
            $port = $isSecure ? 443 : 80;
        }

        // versioning
        $version = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_CSS_FILES_VERSION);

        // merge into target file
        $targetFilename = md5(implode(',', $files) . "|{$hostname}|{$port}|{$version}") . '.css';
        $mergeFilesResult = $this->_mergeFiles(
            $files, $targetDir . DS . $targetFilename,
            false,
            array($this, 'beforeMergeCss'),
            'css'
        );
        if ($mergeFilesResult) {
            return $baseMediaUrl . $mergerDir . '/' . $targetFilename;
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Merge specified javascript files and return URL to the merged file on success
     *
     * @param $files
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMergedJsUrl($files)
    {
        // versioning
        $version = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_CONFIG_JS_FILES_VERSION);

        $targetFilename = md5(implode(',', $files) . "|{$version}") . '.js';
        $targetDir = $this->_initMergerDir('js');
        if (!$targetDir) {
            return '';
        }
        if ($this->_mergeFiles($files, $targetDir . DS . $targetFilename, false, null, 'js')) {
            return Mage::getBaseUrl('media', Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()) . 'js/' . $targetFilename;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation with a Magento site and it was an issue with the server side cache. I was able to correct the problem by having the cache server restarted. I had to contact my site hosting company in order to have them do the restart.